# Titanium FaveBook Tutorial doesn't work as documented

Tags: titanium

Environment Info:

Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.2.1, Titanium SDK version 3.2.1.GA
Running Ubuntu 13.10
Android Emulator
Studio: Build: jenkins-titanium-rcp-master-95 (origin/master)
Date: 04 February 2014, 11:47:38

I'm working with the tutorial here:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Creating_Your_First_Titanium_App

Most everything is working, just up to the end where I add the "Allow user to add books" logic.

views/addbook.xml looks like this:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
    <View layout="vertical">
    <TextField id="titleInput" hintText="Title..."></TextField>
    <TextField id="authorInput" hintText="Author..."></TextField>
    <Button id="insertBookButton" onClick="addBook">Add</Button>        
</View>
</Window>   
</Alloy>
```

controllers/addbook.js looks like this:

```
var myBooks = Alloy.Collection.books; 

function addBook(event) {
    var book = Alloy.createModel('books', {
        title : $.titleInput.value,
        author : $.authorInput.value
});

myBooks.add(book);
book.save();
// Close the window.
$.addbook.close();
}
```

When I go to run the app however, I get:

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1237,1237] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,1238] - In alloy/controllers/index.js:34,13
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [12,1250] - Message: Uncaught ReferenceError: addBook is not defined
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,1250] - Source:             addBook ? $.__views.addBook.addEventListener("click", addBook) : _
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at alloy/controllers/index.js:34: Uncaught ReferenceError: addBook is not defined
```

Following advice on the Titanium forum, http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/162650/having-problems-with-the-creating-your-first-titanium-app-example-at-httpdocsappceleratorcomtitaniumlatestguidecreat works me around the initial issue.

After making that change, the next error I get is:

```
TiExceptionHandler: (main) [4076,4076] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [2,4078] - In alloy/controllers/addbook.js:47,35
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [19,4097] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'books' of undefined
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,4098] - Source:     var myBooks = Alloy.Collection.books;
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at alloy/controllers/addbook.js:47: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'books' of undefined
```

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be welcomed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myBooks = Alloy.Collection.books;
```

should have been

```
var myBooks = Alloy.Collections.books;
```

After that its working.

Comment: Did you copy the wrong line directly from the tutorial, or enter it manually? The line you mention does say `var myBooks = Alloy.Collections.books;` ('collections' plural, not singular).

Comment: I don't recall at this point, I need to go back and take a look.